# CSS : Fancy horizontal line oval shape shadow

Tags: html, css

I can't find what called is this horizontal line, how can I make something like this

[image]

This looks similar to what I want but how can I add shadow same to image above

```
hr.style14 { 
  border: 0; 
  height: 1px; 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0); 
}
```

Comment: Search for box-shadow property.

Comment: How about a radial gradient? https://jsfiddle.net/bjcg458g/

Comment: @JosephMarikle Wow so clean If they just not mark as duplicate

Comment: Yeah.  It's unfortunate.  It is kind of a duplicate, but I'm not sure how you would get any updated answers that use more modern CSS without asking it again.  Oh well.

Comment: Also look at http://jsfiddle.net/yLbtC/1296/.